# SQL left Join with no matches in where

Tags: sql, join

This is an example of a query :

```
SELECT ITEM.ID
     , DAT1.DATE
     , DAT2.DATE
     , DAT3.DATE
FROM ITEM 
   LEFT JOIN DATES AS DAT1 ON DAT1.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ID
   LEFT JOIN DATES AS DAT2 ON DAT2.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ID
   LEFT JOIN DATES AS DAT3 ON DAT3.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ID
WHERE ITEM.ID > 2000
   AND DAT1.FUNCTCODE ='START'
   AND DAT2.FUNCTCODE ='END'
   AND DAT3.FUNCTCODE ='REFURBISHED'
```

Is it possible to always get ITEMS with ID's above 2000 AND
Display dates with 'function codes'(1,2 or 3 fields) or display NULL if row not exist with function code ?

Thanks

Comment: sure, just remove the funccode stuff. as written, you're REQUIRING that the returned records have those three codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `where` conditions on all but the first table to the `on` clauses:

```
SELECT ITEM.ID, DAT1.DATE, DAT2.DATE, DAT3.DATE
FROM ITEM 
LEFT JOIN DATES AS DAT1 ON DAT1.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ID AND DAT1.FUNCTCODE ='START'
LEFT JOIN DATES AS DAT2 ON DAT2.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ID AND DAT2.FUNCTCODE ='END'
LEFT JOIN DATES AS DAT3 ON DAT3.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ID AND  DAT3.FUNCTCODE ='REFURBISHED'
WHERE ITEM.ID > 2000;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see every item with an id over 2000, regardless of whether it has all the related date records, then drop the last three where conditions.

```
SELECT ITEM.ID,DAT1.DATE,DAT2.DATE,DAT3.DATE
FROM ITEM 
LEFT JOIN DATES AS DAT1 ON DAT1.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ID
LEFT JOIN DATES AS DAT2 ON DAT2.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ID
LEFT JOIN DATES AS DAT3 ON DAT3.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ID
WHERE ITEM.ID > 2000
```

This will give you results that look like this:

```
ID    DATE    DATE    DATE
2001  null    null    null    (item with no corresponding date records)
2002  <date>  <date>  <date>  (item with all three date records)
2003  <date>  null    null    (item with only the first date record)
```